# SURF normalisation and Haar wavelet

Tags: image-processing, filters, feature-extraction, scale-space

I am reading the SURF paper ([Speeded-Up Robust Features (SURF)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cviu.2007.09.014)) but can't understand two things. In 3.2 it says:

> Furthermore, the filter responses are normalised with respect to their size. This guarantees a constant Frobenius
> norm for any filter size, an important aspect for the scale
> space analysis as discussed in the next section.

How is the normalisation done? Dividing each element of the matrix by width * height? This doesn't work because the Frobenius norm isn't constant.

The second thing I dont understand is in 4.1:

> In keeping with the rest,
> also the size of the wavelets are scale dependent and set
> to a side length of 4s. Therefore, we can again use integral
> images for fast filtering.

Why we can use integral image and what size is the filter of Haar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, I understand that the filters are normalized in energy. Suppose that we first consider uniform or box filters of size $(2L+1)\times(2L+1)$ and unit amplitude. Their Frobenius norm are $2L+1$. If you divide the amplitude by $(2L+1)^2$, then the Frobenius not of all filters will be exactly one.

For other filters, such a scale normalization will result in either exact or approximate unit energy (I may add simulation on Gaussians later).

I am note sure to understand the second question. You may find useful explanations on the SURF (Speeded-Up Robust Features) in the paper: [An Analysis of the SURF Method](https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2015/69/), IPOL Journal,Image Processing On Line (Edouard Oyallon, Julien Rabin)

> The SURF method (Speeded Up Robust Features) is a fast and robust
> algorithm for local, similarity invariant representation and
> comparison of images. Similarly to many other local descriptor-based
> approaches, interest points of a given image are defined as salient
> features from a scale-invariant representation. Such a multiple-scale
> analysis is provided by the convolution of the initial image with
> discrete kernels at several scales (box filters). The second step
> consists in building orientation invariant descriptors, by using local
> gradient statistics (intensity and orientation). The main interest of
> the SURF approach lies in its fast computation of operators using box
> filters, thus enabling real-time applications such as tracking and
> object recognition. The SURF framework described in this paper is
> based on the PhD thesis of H. Bay [ETH Zurich, 2009], and more
> specifically on the paper co-written by H. Bay, A. Ess, T. Tuytelaars
> and L. Van Gool [Computer Vision and Image Understanding, 110 (2008),
> pp. 346–359]. An implementation is proposed and used to illustrate the
> approach for image matching. A short comparison with a
> state-of-the-art approach is also presented, the SIFT algorithm of D.
> Lowe [International Journal of Computer Vision, 60 (2004), pp.
> 91–110], with which SURF shares a lot in common.

Comment: thanks for the link

Comment: Would be a good source. They have code as well